# Flutter: How to navigate to a new page using the index of the grid block in the ontap()

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is GridViewcode

```
body: AnimationLimiter(
        child: GridView.count(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(_w / 60),
          crossAxisCount: columnCount,
          children: List.generate(
            8,
            (int index) {
              return InkWell(
                child: AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                  position: index,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  columnCount: columnCount,
                  child: ScaleAnimation(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
                    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    child: FadeInAnimation(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: _w / 30, left: _w / 60, right: _w / 60),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                              blurRadius: 40,
                              spreadRadius: 10,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            appTodoList[index],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: GoogleFonts.laila(
                              textStyle:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () =>

                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyPage(index))),

              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

This part is troubling me:

```
 onTap: () => Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyPage(index))),
);
```

Error message: The name 'MyPage' isn't a class.

I have a class representing a list for each grid block clicked.

- Grid block 1 -> MyPage1()
- Grid block 2 -> MyPage2() etc.

How can I include the index in the name and get it recognised as a class name? Concatenation?

Comment: add your class, update the question with your code

Comment: You'll need a switch statement. `MyPage(1)` is fundamentally different from `MyPage1()`. In Dart you cannot do something like `new MyPage$index()` but you could do `switch (index) { case 1: return MyPage1();}`

Comment: Thanks Richard, where would you place the for example getPage function(index) with switch within it. Somewhere within Inkwell code or in a stateless class called getPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate class names because Flutter doesn't use reflection, you can create a method to display that widget you want based on your condition, like this:

```dart
Widget _getPage(int index){
  switch(index){
    case 1: return Page1();
    case 2: return Page1();
    // and so on
  }
  return Placeholder();
}
```

And call in this way:

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _getPage(index))),
```

**OR**

If you want to use just one widget for all, you can pass the parameter as you are doing, but remove the `const` keyword because it's not constant.

```dart
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPage(index))),
```

And you'll need to create a widget called "MyPage", like this:

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({required this.index});

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page :$index'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```